# How to create a Scratch Card in Android?

Tags: android

I need to create a "Scratch Card" App for my final project in school and can't find the way how to implement the scratching event (How do I create background image and put Grey rectangles over it, so when I will scratch those rectangles I will see the picture under them)

The Implementation must be in Android because I don't how to develop In Objective-C yet.

I saw a reference for Objective-C Implementation, but it's no good as I don't understand it.

My Code is:

```
public class FingerPaint extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            MyView myView = new MyView(this);
            myView.requestFocus();
            myView.PaintObjectInit();
            // setContentView(myView);

            LinearLayout upper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);
            upper.addView(myView);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // MyImageView myImageView = new MyImageView(this);
        // setContentView(myImageView);
    }
}



public class MyView extends View {

    private Paint mPaint;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mBitmapPaint;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.mPaint = new Paint();
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }

    protected void PaintObjectInit() {
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        //mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        //mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        try
        {


        //Bitmap bm1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.scratch).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);;
        //Bitmap bm2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.main).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);;

        //mBitmap = toTransparency(bm1, 0xFFAAAAAA, true, bm2);

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        // mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        // mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Please help regarding this.

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848722/android-scratch-card-app

Comment: It dosen't help me,  i don't understand it very well.

Comment: So scratch card is not so simple.Read about NFC in android.hope it will help.

Comment: Can you more specific on the resource for helping me?

Comment: I mean do i need to learn how to work with NFC and then it will help me?

Comment: @ToffeqAhmad: What does NFC have to do with this?

Comment: Hi Nike, You can help me with this?

Comment: Maybe a goo reference that will explain it to me more!!??

Comment: @Nick: i have develop an application that take info from card when touch to android phone.But that card was a NFC supported device.

Comment: @TofeeqAhmad: can you send me just the scratch implementation?

Comment: sorry but here can not share any code.Not possible for me

Comment: So what can I do? you have a suggest?

Comment: @Sameer have u work on like alphabet letter distibuted and user move fingers on it there hint where to move and not cross region and if he get success than the letter replace by that letter came one by one like cat first c than a etc.. what i have to use etc.Thanx  in advance

Comment: @Sameer like child's learning game

Comment: @Khan:yes i have work on this type of game

Comment: @Sameer can u help me for what to use and tutorial also

Answer (score 11):

I come across this problem recently and then I created a library for this so everyone can have a quick implementation of scratch view, hope this can help those who still looking for answer
https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WScratchView

Comment: Can I use Image as overlay??

Answer (score 4):

I found this library very useful.

https://github.com/sharish/ScratchView

Very easy to integrate

```
<com.cooltechworks.views.ScratchImageView
    android:id="@+id/sample_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:src="@drawable/img_sample2"
/>
```

[image]  [image]

Answer (score 1):

you can make "Scratch Card" application like this way. you need to follow the below code which is working code. you just need to required understand and implement your own logic.

```
public class MainActJava extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        setContentView(new MyView(this, bitmap));
    }

    public class MyView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {

        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
        private Paint mPaint;
        private Bitmap oBitmap;
        private Bitmap holder;
        private Canvas mCanvas;
        private Path mPath;
        private Paint mBitmapPaint;
        private float mX, mY;

        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public MyView(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
            super(context);
            setOnTouchListener(this);
            this.oBitmap = bitmap;
            this.mPaint = new Paint();
            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
            init();
        }

        protected void init() {
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setDither(true);
            mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(35);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            holder = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(holder);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            onDrawing(canvas);
        }

        private void onDrawing(Canvas canvas) {
            mCanvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(oBitmap, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, mBitmapPaint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(holder, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        }

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }

        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }

        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]